# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..9: 100

Tags: flutter, dart

1. I have to face issues like below code when I try to create load more items with GroupedListView.
   Here is UI code I make and have issues when I using GroupListView:

```
  GroupedListView<TrackingOrderItemListResponse, DateTime>(
                      controller: controller.scrollController,
                      key: controller.statePageKey,
                      elements:
                          controller.trackingOrderListResponse!.body.items!,
                      groupBy: (element) => DateTime.parse(
                          DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(element.orderDate)),
                      groupComparator: (value1, value2) {
                        return value2.compareTo(value1);
                      },
                      useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      groupSeparatorBuilder: (DateTime value) {
                        var dateStr;
                        var dNow = DateTime.now();
                        if (value.isAtSameMomentAs(
                            DateTime(dNow.year, dNow.month, dNow.day))) {
                          dateStr = "Today";
                        } else {
                          dateStr = DateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").format(value);
                        }
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Text(
                            dateStr,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (c, data) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
                          child: TrackingCell(
                            trackingController: controller,
                            data: data,
                            onTap: () => controller.gotoDetailPage(data.id),
                            onReorder: () async {
                              Get.toNamed(Routes.EXPRESS_DETAILS, arguments: {
                                "is_reorder": true,
                                "id": data.id,
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    )
```

I have to face issues like below UI code when I try to create load more items with GroupedListView.
And here is my controller:

```
  fetchMoreTrackingOrder(
    String startData, String endData, int page, int rpp) async {
  scrollController.addListener(() async {
    if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent ==
        scrollController.position.pixels) {
      page += 1;
      print("Information page: $page");
      var resData = await _trackingService.trackingListOrder(
          endData, startData, page, rpp, currentStatus);
      if (page == 1) {
        trackingOrderListResponse = resData;
      } else {
        trackingOrderListResponse!.body.items!.addAll(resData!.body.items!);
      }
      update();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please copy your code instead of uploading an image.

Comment: Also, there's no line indication in the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @MKarimi I'm already pushing code in there.

Comment: @il_boga, it show message like this: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..9: 100

Comment: I meant to have a reference to which line of code caused the error: the error itself is simply telling you that you're trying to access the index 100 of an array (or list, or something like that) that has only 10 elements. Without knowing where this happen, it's kinda hard helping you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.